# First Date of Each Week in a Month

Tags: php, date

I am having a small issue where I have the month (December 2013) and the Week Number (1, 2, 3 etc) and I need to find out the first date of each week.

I cannot do a simple search like finding the closest Sunday relative to a date since some weeks don't start on a Sunday at all.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you have the date of 1st of any month :

- First find the `next Sunday`
- Then add 1 week at a time to it to get subsequent Sunday's

Code :

```
$firstDayOfMonth = '2013-12-01';    // Try also with first day of other months

$week1 = $firstDayOfMonth;
$week2 = date( "Y-m-d" ,strtotime('next Sunday', strtotime( $week1 ) ) );
$week3 = date( "Y-m-d" ,strtotime('+1 week', strtotime( $week2 ) ) );
$week4 = date( "Y-m-d" ,strtotime('+1 week', strtotime( $week3 ) ) );
$week5 = date( "Y-m-d" ,strtotime('+1 week', strtotime( $week4 ) ) );

echo '
Week 1 starts on : ' .$week1 .'<br>
Week 2 starts on : ' .$week2 .'<br>
Week 3 starts on : ' .$week3 .'<br>
Week 4 starts on : ' .$week4 .'<br>
Week 5 starts on : ' .$week5 .'<br>';
```

Output :

```
Week 1 starts on : 2013-12-01
Week 2 starts on : 2013-12-08
Week 3 starts on : 2013-12-15
Week 4 starts on : 2013-12-22
Week 5 starts on : 2013-12-29
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
<?php

     $first_day_this_month = date('M-D-Y',strtotime(date('M-01-Y')));
     echo date('M-D-Y',strtotime(date('M-01-Y')))." = ".date('M-d-Y',strtotime(date('M-01-Y')));//First day of month
     echo "<br>";   
     $last_day_this_month  = date('t');//last day of month
     $last_day_num=intval($last_day_this_month);

    for($i=1;$i<$last_day_num;$i++)
    {

         $first_day_this_month = date('M-D-Y',strtotime(date('M-'.$i.'-Y')));//All day of month
         $dateopt_arr=date('M-N-Y',strtotime(date('M-'.$i.'-Y')));
        $dateo=explode('-',$dateopt_arr);
        //echo $dateo[1];
        if(($dateo[1]%7)==0)
        {
            echo $first_day_this_month = date('M-D-Y',strtotime(date('M-'.$i.'-Y')))." = ".date('M-d-Y',strtotime(date('M-'.$i.'-Y')));//Week day of month
            echo "<br>";
        }   
    }


 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the second argument of strtotime to specify the date to calculate "next Sunday" and other relative dates from:

```
strtotime('next Sunday', strtotime('09/12/2013'));
```

https://www.php.net/strtotime

Example:

```
echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime('next Sunday', strtotime('09/12/2013')));
```

Comment: I need the first day of a week. Not necessarily a Sunday. For instance, if the week only has a Friday and Saturday, the code must return the date of the Friday since its the first day of that particular week

Comment: strtotime('this week', time()); 
Replace time(). Next sunday/last monday methods won't work when the current day is sunday/monday.